# How can I make vertical scroll bar invisible?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, vertical-scrolling

How do I make a vertical and or horizontal scroll bar invisible on a `JScrollPane` in java.

I've tried this, but doesn't work:

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setVisible(false);
```

Also, I would like to know how to make the bar visible again once it is not at a null state (I don't know the technical term) i.e, see pic below. Bar is visible, but at a "null" state.

[image]

Also, is there a way to have the scroll bar remain invisible, but still allow for scrolling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you want is [JScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setVerticalScrollBarPolicy%28int%29)

Valid values are:

> - ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED
> - ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER
> - ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS

I'm not entirely sure what you need, but it seems that you want to be using `ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED`.

If those policies are not enough, you can write your wrapped view to implement the [Scrollable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface, and you can change the policy inside the [Scrollable.getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html#getScrollableTracksViewportHeight%28%29) method.